# TFS vs Perforce (Retrieving files upto a changelist)

Tags: tfs, perforce, snapshot

In perforce, if one syncs to a specific changelist, a snapshot of src repo as of that changelist is pulled down. Is there a way of doing the same thing in TFS? Does TFS changeset represent a specific snapshot at all?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Perforce and its terminology, but if I'm understanding your question correctly, you're asking how to retrieve a copy of the code at a specific point in time, or as of a specific set of changes?

In TFS, you would do that using the Get Specific Version command, and then you can choose a Date, or a specific Changeset.

Comment: You are correct.  I've used both Perforce and TFS and I believe you accurately answered his question.  Changelists work the same way in Perforce and Changesets in TFS.